# C++ accessing upper scope instead of global

Tags: c++, scope

You can find my code and its output below. What prefix(or something else) should I use in "SOMETHING" to access j in the mid level (j==2) ?

I tried

> main::j

But it didn't work.

The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
int j=3;//global
using std::cout;using std::endl;
int main(){
int j=2;//mid
cout<<"inside general main:\n";
cout<<"cout<<j---"<<j<<endl;//prints 2
cout<<"cout<<::j---"<<::j<<endl;//prints 3
cout<<"inside for loop:\n";
for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
    int j=1;//inside
    cout<<"cout<<j---"<<j<<endl;//prints 1
    cout<<"cout<<::j---"<<::j<<endl;//prints 3
    //cout<<"cout<<::j---"<<SOMETHING<<endl;//prints 2
}
return 0;
}
```

The Output:

```
inside general main:
cout<<j---2
cout<<::j---3
inside for loop:
cout<<j---1
cout<<::j---3
```

Comment: One solution would be not to shadow your variables in the first place, it's a bad habbit.

Comment: There's no way of getting the previous scope. Use sensible naming for your variables and this hopefully won't happen.

Comment: Some developers/teams have a convention for naming that distinguishes names based on their scope, e.g I've seen prefixing (m_ for member, s_ for static, g_ for global, t_ for thread-local, etc) or suffixing (some places use _ for member variables, some for function parameters).

Comment: I know that it is a bad habit. I am reading C++ book, I was reading about local and global access to the variables with the same name, but didn't see anything for intermediate elements with the same name. My question is purely educational.

Comment: avoid `_` prefix for member variables. I heard it was dangerous, probably because of the already `_` prefixed symbols. Prefer `m_` for instance.

Comment: to get the previous scope, just create a static function that returns `j`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How should that be accomplished if the previous scope is inside a function? Nested functions aren't allowed. Lambdas could solve this, but then the problem is if there are multiple levels of scoping, with variables with the same name in multiple scopes. Bad idea I know, but it's not really that easy to work around in a reliable way.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I meant: a global scope function. If I had a solution to generate such a function from within the `main` I would have answered. Maybe looking into the executable and extracting the symbol table (if available) could work, but renaming the variable also works :)

Comment: So I guess summary is that syntax doesn't provide direct access, possibly reference or obviously changing the name would be the best solution

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: In a question about scopes you **could**, for example, indent your code.

Comment: If we get address of the global j inside the for loop, an the address of local j in the for loop, we would get two addresses which don't hold the desired value. We have defined 3rd j in main(one that hold 2), and one i, the correct address is either remaining j, or the address of i. Is there a way to get a list of all allocated memory cells by this program? If yes then we can access by exclusion of those which are not for sure. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no qualification that refers to a local scope.

Just use different names.

Comment: Can you please refer to my last comment under the question?

Comment: Maybe you mean "Is there a way to get a list of all allocated memory cells by this program?". No.

Comment: Yes I meant that question.

Comment: OK, then no, no such facility. Tip: you can use free tools like **AStyle** (artistic style) to automatically format your code.